# Scala & Spark: Only one CPU utilized

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I identified a snippet of code, that extremely harms the parallelization of the following program (ML pipeline). It's purpose was to "digitalize" a column, e.g. transforming a column "int" with values `Array(0,1,2,0,3)` into `Array(0,1,1,0,1)`.

The (terrible) code causing the issue was

```
dfBin = df
   .filter(df("int") > 0)
   .withColumn("int",org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit(1)
   .union(df.filter(df("int") === 0))
```

[image: CPU utilazation during training]

Clearly a better code to achieve this is

```
dfBin = df.withColumn("bin",when(df("int") === 0,0).otherwise(1))
```

[image: CPU utilazation during training]

The question: Why does the first snippet stop Spark to parallelize and how do I identify such harmfull pieces of code faster in the future?

Comment: You already identified your first attempt as terrible code, so perhaps avoiding it in the future is the solution.

Comment: The first snippit causes df to be evaluated twice.  I'm not sure if that's the only part of the problem but it is certainly something you should look to avoid.  Remember that a Dataframe isn't data, it's an execution plan.

Comment: The probability, that I'm going to code the exact same code is approximately zero. Therefore, understanding why (or the rules behind, thx puhlen) might be the better / less pragmatic option.

Comment: Is the 2nd execution faster in clock time? or are we seeing the same 60 seconds that both take to complete?

Comment: the first option never (I aborted after 5 hours) finishes, while the second takes approx. 15min to finish. So both CPU usage plots are only a part of the whole computation.